# How to handle text file in python

Tags: python, data-extraction

I have a file name called `words.txt` having Dictionary words in it. I call this file and ask the user to enter a word. Then try to find out whether this word is present in this file or not if yes print `True` else `Word not found`.

```
wordByuser  = input("Type a Word:")
file = open('words.txt', 'r')
    
if wordByuser in file: #or if wordByuser==file:
    print("true")
else:
    print("No word found")
```

The words.txt files contain each letter in a single line and then the new letter on the second line.

Comment: You should first read the file contents to a variable. Try file.readlines() or file.read()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the `file` first, also use `snake_case` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

```
user_word  = input("Type a Word:")
with open('words.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()
    if user_word in content:
        print(True)
    else:
        print('Word not found')
```

Comment: Code works. but i don't understand with and as you use in 2nd line. please can you explain or give me a link about these(Youtube or Stackoverflow.com) Thanks

Comment: @Shani so when you use `file = open('text.txt')` later on you have to close that file, when you use `with open('file')` it creates a loop that closes the file after the loop is completed. `as` just lets you assign the file to a variable name

Answer (score 3):

Use this one line solution:

```
lines = file.read().splitlines()
if wordByuser in lines:
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

This function should do it:

```
def searchWord(wordtofind):
    with open('words.txt', 'r') as words:
        for word in words:
            if wordtofind == word.strip():
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `.read()` to the file class you initiated.

Like this:

```
wordByuser  = input("Type a Word:")
file = open('words.txt', 'r')
data = file.read()
if wordByuser in data:
    print("true")
else:
    print("No word found")
```